# Python web interface for MQTT

Tags: python, web, interface, mqtt

I have been working on a project which involves multiple raspberry pi computers controlled using MQTT on a server computer. 
The system is working well but at the moment I am manually publishing using the mosquitto command line interface to control the computers. I would like to set up a web interface on the local server so that I can control the computers using my phone/ipad etc.
I would like to have buttons that publish to a specific topics and also a control that will accept text and publish to a topic with the text as the payload. 
I don’t have a lot of experience in web programming and I would like use python if possible as I am already familiar with it. 
does anyone have any suggestions as to how i would implement it and where i can find a tutorial?
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) to build a web interface to forward messages to MQTT

Or you could use the [Paho MQTT js](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/jsdoc/symbols/Paho.MQTT.Client.html) library and a MQTT server that supports websockets (e.g. mosquitto 1.4) and send MQTT messages directly from the webpage.